# Can you Join the imperials after starting the the stormcloak quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Can you join the **Imperials** Once you have started ***"Joining the Stormcloaks"*** ?

Cause I wanted to join the **Stormcloaks** but then I saw how racist  **Ulfric** was and wanted to join ***The Imperial Legion***.

I am playing on PS3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can switch sides until you have

> completed the quest "The Jagged Crown", as stated here:
> http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/The_Jagged_Crown_(Quest)
> "*While the Jagged Crown is in the possession of the Dragonborn, they can also decide to travel to the capital city of the opposition to hand over the crown to either General Tullius in Solitude or Jarl Ulfric Stormcloak in Windhelm. The leader of the opposing faction will accept the crown and unceremoniously recognize the Dragonborn as a member of their faction. From there on, the Dragonborn will fight the Civil War for their new allies.* "